# Error installing netbeans Primefaces CRUD Generator plugin

Tags: netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I am using Netbeans 7.3 with installed Primefaces 3.4. I am trying to install the netbeans Primefaces CRUD generator plugin and i am getting the following error attached:
[image]
Please help me in resolving this problem.

Thanks in advance
Senthil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the plugin (nbm file) works with only Netbeans 7.2.1.Using this plugin (nbm file) in Netbeans 7.1.1 or Netbeans 7.3 doesn't work.

Thanks
Senthil